# GoAway Frame With Invalid Control frame in http2

Tags: networking, https, tls1.2, http2, nghttp2

I have a proxy server that will do handshake with browser and read data from browser and then proxy server will connect to remote server and sends that data to remote server and vice versa.

Both the connection (i.e: browser to proxy server and proxy-server to remote server) are using HTTP/2 network protocol. Proxy server after doing handshake with browser and remote server, it will tunnel all the data between them. Small sites like [www.nghttp2.org](https://www.nghttp2.org/) are working fine. But for larger sites like [facebook.com](https://facebook.com), or [gmail.com](https://gmail.com), the browser (chrome, firefox, safari) is throwing errors (`INVALID_CONTROL_FRAME` or `too large frame`) in a `GOAWAY` frame. The proxy server will tunnel all the frames (i.e: `HEADERS`, `DATA`, `WINDOW_UPDATE`, etc.,).

In HTTP/2 RFC, I read that:

> Both types of flow control are hop by hop, that is, only between thetwo endpoints.  Intermediaries do not forward WINDOW_UPDATE frames between dependent connection

Is anything i have to do with that? Can anyone help me out to find solution for this error?

Comment: Is this a proxy you wrote? Which technologies do you use? Does the proxy have some sort of log that dumps all the frames that go through?

Comment: yes it's a proxy. Are you asking which programming language that am using ? Am using C++ programming language. Proxy dumps all the frames.

Comment: Could you post the frames before the GOAWAY frame?